# How to get theme data from youtrack api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtrack

I try now to create a cool YouTrack widget, but I have a little problem, after a long time of searching I cannot find any way to get a selected youtrack theme (dark or light) to use it in the widget, have anyone a ideea how to read this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible to get the dark mode flag from the REST API, I'd rather advice against that. The flag is not a part of the public API, so it can be changed or removed anytime without further notice.

What I would suggest instead is to rely on CSS variables to define background and text color. Please refer to https://github.com/JetBrains/youtrack-issues-list-widget/blob/master/src/app/style/issues-list-widget.scss for an example.

If you still need to access the flag from JS code, the following trick may help

```js
function isDarkMode() {
   const bgColor = getComputedStyle(document.body).
            getPropertyValue('--ring-content-background-color').trim();
   return bgColor !== '#fff';
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Would you be interested to publish the widget to https://plugins.jetbrains.com for other to enjoy it once it's ready?

Comment: I have to see when I'm done with it, because actually it only works with a certain backend server, where I can deploy the server, or I change it to open-source.